# DFS - Active Directory Namespace not showing

Tags: domain, dfs, network-share

Appologies if this doesn't make sense - I'm just starting to play with DFS and some of the terms are still confusing to me.

We have created a couple of DFS roots (as domain roots) on our domain and set up replication and all appears to be working great.  The only problem, and i don't know if it is a problem or working as intended is that although I can navigate to the root namespaces by opening \domain.local\Shares (Shares being the root namespace) I am not able to see the Roots if I browse to \domain.local.

I would like my users to be able to see all the available roots by browsing from just the domain - is this possible?  Have I done something wrong?

I don't know if it is important but DFS and the Shares are running on two member file servers in seperate sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seen expected behaviour. When you browse \domain.local you have issued a DC referral and have been directed to a DC for a list of shares. You will see SYSVOL, Netlogon and any other shares explicitly configured on the DC you happen to be browsing.

See http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2009/04/15/understanding-windows-server-2008-dfs-n-by-analyzing-network-traces.aspx for some explanations of what happens on the wire when browsing DFS shares. You will also likely find the open specification details on MSDN useful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc227068(v=PROT.13).aspx